# OpenCV C++ template matching / correlation

Tags: c++, opencv, correlation, convolution, template-matching

I have the following issue:
Like shown in the sketch below I have a 900x900px source image and a smaller 300x300px template image. Now I need to calculate the correlation between a arbitrary subsection of the source image and a rotated image of the template image. The rotation angle (phi) as well as the coordinates of the subsection (x, y) are given and I only need to calculate the correlation. However I need to repeat the whole operation for different combinations of x, y and phi very often.

[image: sketch]

I intend to use opencv (version 3.1) for this task. Because I need to repeat the operation for different combinations of x, y and phi given the same source and template images I am looking for a very fast solution.
At the moment I rotate the template given the angle using warpAffine() and afterwards I use the matchTemplate() function to calculate the correlation.
However matchTemplate() seems to calculate more a convolution instead of a plain correlation and I think I missused it. Also the matchTemplate() part is the bottleneck of my program.
Do you have any idea how to speed this up?
Is it useful to use graphics accelleration in this case?
Or may it be usefull to store a dft transformed version of my images before i perform the correlation?
Or do you have completely different ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Why it is Time Consuming?**

This type of scanning in an image is time consuming due to number of scans with different number of possibilities (e.g. the template can be rotated by every 2 degrees and then you scan the entire image again and repeat. You can see the growing possibilities of solution space). Moreover, the choice of scanning stride can help increase the search time but likely to miss the optimal solution due to larger jump intervals.

**GPU Implementation**

GPU implementation can help increase the speed but there is not guarantee. You the GPU implementation in OpenCV [cv::cuda::TemplateMatching](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/d58/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1TemplateMatching.html)

**Other Approaches**

Depending on your template type i.e. textured or textureless, etc. you can carefully craft features that are scale invariant such as SIFT which will be relatively faster than dense template matching. As you image sizes are large, real time SIFT detection will be difficult but yet I can assure it i will be faster than the method u using now.

You can check you [this paper](http://www.embedded-vision.com/sites/default/files/apress/computervisionmetrics/chapter6/9781430259299_Ch06.pdf) on some reviews of image features.